# Unable todeploy war file in Tomcat 7.0.69 application

Tags: java, tomcat7

I need to migrate an existing project built using Java 1.5 and Tomcat 5.5 to Java 1.8 using Tomcat server 7.0.69.

Whenever i tried to deploy my war file in the Tomcat 7.0.69 application, i got the following exception

I am using Java 1.8 to build this application.

Here the error from "catalina.log":

```
Jun 11, 2016 10:25:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/sample]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:363)
    at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:969)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig(ContextConfig.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:898)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:387)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5472)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more

Jun 11, 2016 10:25:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive C:\Work\software\test1.8\apache-tomcat-7.0.69\webapps\sample.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ddsgui]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: the root Caused is: java.lang.NullPointerException. Look to see if you have configured security correctly.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess at some problem with your app's `META-INF/context.xml` file.

Comment: Hi Minh, can u please tell me how to check whether I have configured the security correctly

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue.  I resolved it by removing the following from my project's web.xml file.

```
<login-config>
    <realm-name>Device-Monitor</realm-name>
</login-config>
```